# How can I get my header elements to line up in a row properly?

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've designated a background image for the whole page. On top of this I would like to have a header, with a solid background color, with my logo on the left side, business name in the middle, and my name on the right side.

Below this I would like 3 columns for the main page of my site, each probably with their own background color if that's possible.

I'm trying to use bootstrap to give my header three sections (logo-text-name), and I'd like the text to be centred.

The reason I have so much padding is because the logo kept hanging out the bottom of the header.

Now I'm sure there's a lot I'm doing wrong, but if anyone could help I'd be eternally grateful. Thanks.

```css
body {
  background-image: url(images/bg.jpg);
}

header {
  background-color: #539e8a;
  padding: 20px 10px 30px 10px;
  color: #f6c5be;
  border-radius: 25px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  height: 180px;
}

#logo {
  width: 160px;
  height: 140px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-2">
          <img id="logo" src="https://via.placeholder.com/160x140" alt="cakes 'n' bakes logo">
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-8">
          <h1>Cakes 'n' Bakes</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-2">
          <p>my name</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>

  <div class="container">
    <div id="main" class="row">
      <div id="col1" class="col-sm-4">
        <h2> col 1 </h2>
      </div>
      <div id="col2" class="col-sm-4">
        <h2> col 2 </h2>
      </div>
      <div id="col3" class="col-sm-4">
        <h2> col 3 </h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: As you can see I've created a demo of your code. Please revise your post to try and simplify, just hitting on the key aspects of your question. There's a lot up there that isn't really relevant. Be very clear about the problem and spare us the expressions of frustration. We all understand and sympathize, but it's a distraction here. We're not a discussion forum.

Comment: Protip: Floats are a dated technique. They're almost non-existent in recent versions of Bootstrap, and you generally shouldn't use them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap 5 really brings [flexbox](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/utilities/flex/) to the table, so I'd use that rather than wrestling with columns, which can be troublesome due to inflexibility.

Here I've replaced your container, row, and columns with a simple flex row. Item alignment on the cross axis centers things up. The center element has Bootstrap's `flex-fill` class on it to make it stretch.

Also notice that I've replaced your custom margin and padding with Bootstrap
[spacing classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/utilities/spacing/) to clean things up.

```css
body {
  background-image: url(https://via.placeholder.com/1200);
}

header {
  background-color: #539e8a;
  color: #f6c5be;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

#logo {
  width: 160px;
  height: 140px;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <header class="mt-3">
    <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
      <img id="logo" src="https://via.placeholder.com/160x140" alt="cakes 'n' bakes logo" class="logo m-3">

      <div class="flex-fill text-center">
        <h1>Cakes 'n' Bakes</h1>
      </div>

      <div class="px-3">
        <p>My Name</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>

  <div class="container">
    <div id="main" class="row">
      <div id="col1" class="col-sm-4">
        <h2> col 1 </h2>
      </div>
      <div id="col2" class="col-sm-4">
        <h2> col 2 </h2>
      </div>
      <div id="col3" class="col-sm-4">
        <h2> col 3 </h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

I make some changes and add somethings to your code so I hope I hope I could      help you!

```css
body {
  background-image: url(images/bg.jpg);
}

header {
  background-color: #539e8a;
  padding: 20px 10px 0px 0px;
  color: #f6c5be;
  border-radius: 25px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  height: 180px;
}

#logo {
  width: 160px;
  height: 140px;
}

#top-part-1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.col-xs-2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.col-xs-8 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.header-2 {
  padding: 20px 10px 0px 0px;
  color: #000000;
  border-radius: 25px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  height: 180px;
}

#top-part-2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<header>
  <div class="container" id="top-part-1">
    <div class="col-xs-2">
      <img id="logo" src="images/logo.png" alt="cakes 'n' bakes logo">
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-8">
      <h1>Cakes 'n' Bakes</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-2">
      <p>my name</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>

<div class="header-2">
  <div class="container" id="top-part-2">
    <div class="col-xs-2">
      <h2> col 1 </h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-8">
      <h2> col 2 </h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
      <h2> col 3 </h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: by the way i don't use Bootstrap so you'll find Bootstrap codes are deleted!

Comment: Yeah, that's a problem. This is a Bootstrap question and you've replaced the library's classes with a bunch of unnecessary CSS. That's not wise.

Comment: Any suggestions to make my code better? because It hasn't been long since I finished Html and CSS course

Comment: I gave you some. Use the classes that the library provides. There's nothing wrong with your code, but it's not appropriate for this particular problem.